# How can I print a message from a signal handler

Tags: linux, shell, unix, system-calls, systems-programming

I have small project for practice in system calls. The idea is to create a Rock paper scissors game. The controller need to create two child processes and when two processes are created they are supposed to send *ready* command to the controller (parent process) using SIGUSR1 signal. I have created the two children processes and the signal sent the signal to the controller but the problem message does not print out. what am I wrong?

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h> // fork(); for creating processes and pipe()s
#include<signal.h>  
#include<sys/signal.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

 void handle_sigusr1(int sig){
    
      printf("Sending ready command...\n");
    
   }
   
   int x = 0;
int main(int args, char* argv[]){

int player0, player1;

player0 = fork();
if(player0 != 0){

 player1 = fork();

}

if( player0 == 0){
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    sleep(2);
    
}else if(player1 == 0){
    sleep(3);
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
    
}else{
 wait(NULL);
 struct sigaction sa = { 0 };
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sa.sa_handler = &handle_sigusr1;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    
    if(signal(SIGUSR1, handle_sigusr1)){
       x++;
       printf("Controller: Received ready command. Total %d\n", x);
      
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, there are 2 major issues to modify.

First of all, move the signal handler above the wait() function, otherwise you are defining how to handle the signal after receiving it

```
signal(SIGUSR1, handle_sigusr1);
wait();
```

Then, the parent process is waiting for only 1 child to receive the signal. You should add a loop to wait both the child processes in the parent statement branch